# Vertical align text including ahref and/or fontawesome icons

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How is it possible to vertically align content in a div with flexbox, including html elements and/or fontawesome icons? Please check the code snippet below:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.alert {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px 40px 15px 24px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 0;
}
.alert a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.alert .fa-info-circle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
    1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur mollitia repudiandae consectetur ducimus, expedita eum eius, hic ipsa cupiditate assumenda tempore atque, itaque nostrum dolorem distinctio error dolorum ullam iste unde ab. Aut eveniet ratione mollitia a. Veniam, eum quidem. Debitis hic, rem ea ex ad fuga pariatur quae sint.
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
    2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <a href="#">some link</a>Aspernatur mollitia repudiandae consectetur ducimus, expedita eum eius, hic ipsa cupiditate assumenda.
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
    3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <a href="#">some link</a>Aspernatur mollitia repudiandae consectetur ducimus <i class="fa fa-home"></i> expedita eum eius, hic ipsa cupiditate assumenda.
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur mollitia repudiandae consectetur ducimus expedita eum eius, hic ipsa cupiditate assumenda.
  </div>
</div>
```

Alert number 1 works as intended.

Alert number 2 shows an example with an ahref element, but now the whole content is divided into columns.

Alert number 3 shows the same problem, this time including a fontawesome icon.

Alert number 4 works as intended, without a main icon.

If this is not possible with flexbox, what options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to achieve this? Just wrap your text into a `<span>` tag.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.alert {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px 40px 15px 24px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 0;
}
.alert a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.alert .fa-info-circle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
    <span>1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur mollitia repudiandae consectetur ducimus, expedita eum eius, hic ipsa cupiditate assumenda tempore atque, itaque nostrum dolorem distinctio error dolorum ullam iste unde ab. Aut eveniet ratione mollitia a. Veniam, eum quidem. Debitis hic, rem ea ex ad fuga pariatur quae sint.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
    <span>2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <a href="#">some link</a>Aspernatur mollitia repudiandae consectetur ducimus, expedita eum eius, hic ipsa cupiditate assumenda.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
    <span>3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <a href="#">some link</a>Aspernatur mollitia repudiandae consectetur ducimus <i class="fa fa-home"></i> expedita eum eius, hic ipsa cupiditate assumenda.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <span>4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur mollitia repudiandae consectetur ducimus expedita eum eius, hic ipsa cupiditate assumenda.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, thanks for the simple solution. But is this the only solution? You see, I have these alerts spread all over my projects and it will be a pain to edit all of those alerts..

Comment: It's a good practice in the first place to always have text inside any kind of tag, since it makes the content/text more manageable. If this is the only solution to this problem? probably not. I'll check if there's another easier-to-implement solution, but I can't garanty you any success :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use container inside your flex container if you don't want many columns. In you case you can use two div container inside the alert container: one for the icon and one for the content.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.alert {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px 40px 15px 24px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 0;
}
.alert a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.alert .fa-info-circle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
    1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur mollitia repudiandae consectetur ducimus, expedita eum eius, hic ipsa cupiditate assumenda tempore atque, itaque nostrum dolorem distinctio error dolorum ullam iste unde ab. Aut eveniet ratione mollitia a. Veniam, eum quidem. Debitis hic, rem ea ex ad fuga pariatur quae sint.
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-info">
      <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
      <div class="alert-content">
        2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <a 
        href="#">some link </a>Aspernatur mollitia repudiandae 
        consectetur ducimus, expedita eum eius, hic ipsa cupiditate 
        assumenda.
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
    <div class="alert-content">
    3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <a 
     href="#">some link</a>Aspernatur mollitia repudiandae consectetur 
    ducimus 
     <i class="fa fa-home"></i> expedita eum eius, hic ipsa cupiditate 
     assumenda.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur mollitia repudiandae consectetur ducimus expedita eum eius, hic ipsa cupiditate assumenda.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, just like kevin b. his answer. Thanks for the simple solution. But is this the only solution? You see, I have these alerts spread all over my projects and it will be a pain to edit all of those alerts..